# 4th order tensor

Tags: pde, python, fenics, tensor

I'm new with FEniCS and Python and I'm stuck with this issue:
is there a way to write a 4th order tensor in an easy way to implement?

I have to compute the following stiffnes tensor:

$A_{ijkl}= \lambda \delta_{ij}\delta_{kl} + \mu (\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl} + \delta_{il}\delta_{jk})$

Comment: You should really ask this over on the [FEniCS forums](http://fenicsproject.org/qa/).